# undefined reference with irrklang code blocks

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, codeblocks, irrklang

I'm losing hope to finish my work. I did a game with irrlicht on Code Blocks. I linked irrlicht it works but impossible to link irrKlang...
It shows me the same message each time.

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Llib\irrlicht-1.8.3\lib\Win32-gcc -Llib\irrKlang-1.5.0\lib\Win32-gcc -Llib\irrlicht-1.8.3\lib\Win32-gcc -Llib\irrKlang-1.5.0\lib\Win32-gcc -Llib\irrKlang-1.5.0\bin\win32-gcc -o BomberPark.exe .objs\main.o .objs\srcs\AppSetting.o .objs\srcs\Bombs.o .objs\srcs\Camera.o
.objs\srcs\Sound.o:Sound.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to irrklang::createIrrKlangDevice(irrklang::E_SOUND_OUTPUT_DRIVER, int, char const*, char const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I did these things: I added the libirrklang.a in link librairies and add the directory of the includes in compiler + added the lib directory in linker so I wanted to know what else can I do to resolve my problem please?

The screenshots of my configuration for the linker:

[conf1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuEqi.png)

[conf3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHrVX.png)

Comment: To get help with a linkage error you need to post the at least the failing linker command and the errors that follow from it, copied from the build log. You'll find the build log in the Code::Blocks **Build log** tab (not the
**Build messages** tab) after a failing build. The failing linker command is the last `g++ ...` command in the build log, followed by the errors.

Comment: I edited my post but I'm really stuck with this... I followed every tutorials I found to the letter and it refuses to compile... I linked irrlicht to my project but irrklang doesn't want to be linked ... @MikeKinghan

Comment: "I added the libirrklang.a in link librairies". That linker commandline says you haven't. You've got 5 `-Ldirectory` options (2 of them duplicates of others) to tell the linker what dirs to search for the libraries, but you have no `-lirrKlang` to tell it search for `libirrKlang.a`. You have no `-l` (library) options at all. You'd better post screenshots of your project's **Build options** -> **Linker settings** and **Build options** -> **Compiler settings**.

Comment: I put in my post the screenshots of my Build options -> Linker Settings & Build options -> Search Directories -> Linker. I swear that the libs.a are in these directories. I also added the include directories of my libs and my project to compiler so that's why I'm stucked. @MikeKinghan

Comment: @kilmat: It doesn't matter whether those directories contain the relevant libraries. You have to link with the libraries. Or library.

Comment: ok but I thought when I added them in the linker settings it was good? however how can I do that? @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: @kilmat The screenshots can't account for the commandline, but they don't indicate
which target of three targets you're building or the policy by which
target options inherit project options (or don't). Anyhow even if you
sorted the C::B config you couldn't build the project because you're
trying to link 32-bit libraries (`lib\Win32-gcc\libIrrlicht.a`,`\bin\win32-gcc\irrKlang.dll`)
with a 64-bit compiler (`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`) and its 64-bit
standard libraries, which won't work. 64|32-bit binaries link with
matching toolchain.

Comment: @kilmat And there's other strangeness in your config. You're trying to instruct a GUI (CodeBlocks) to drive
GNU `make` and the GCC commandline compiler and linker to build your project while you don't well 
understand how to drive them yourself. Take a step back and learn, for instance, how to
compile and link the programs in `irrKlang-1.5.0\examples` with GCC
at the command prompt. Use [this tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) to get going. When you can do that
you'll no longer flounder with Code::Blocks.

Comment: With gcc you link a library by using the lowercase `-l` option.